# Samples/file extensions supported by iOS sampler

Tags: ios, core-audio, sample

I'm writing an iOS app which can play MIDI and output its content using the AUSampler and AUGraph classes. I know for sure it supports files like Soundfont (.sf2) but this one seems to be quite antiquated.

**Question: Are there any other files or sample types which this framework supports?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AUSampler also supports [DLS format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLS_format) (.dls) and [AUpreset format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011217) (.aupreset)